# Specifying JSON value in OPENJSON SQL query

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

I'm inserting data into a table using data from a JSON-file. I want to set a bit column `isMain` to 1 at the same time. I tried so by using the code below, but it throws an error saying it's incorrect syntax. How could I achieve this?

```
INSERT INTO Company
(
    OrganizationNumber,
    Name
    IsMain
)
SELECT company.*
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '<path to json-file>', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
WITH (
    organizationNumber NVARCHAR(255) '$.organizationNumber',
    name NVARCHAR(255) '$.name',
    isMain BIT '1'
)
AS company;
```

Comment: Define `IsMain` in your `SELECT`, not your `OPENJSON`'s `WITH` clause. (`SELECT organizationNumber, [name], 1 FROM...`)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)
declare @tmp as table(organizationNumber varchar(20),name varchar(20),IsMain bit)

set @json=N'{
   "data":[
      {
         "organizationNumber":"3888690",
         "name":"bob smith"
      }
   ]
}';



insert into @tmp
(
organizationNumber,
name,
IsMain
)
select 
  JSON_VALUE(c.value,'$.organizationNumber') as organizationNumber, 
 JSON_VALUE(c.value,'$.name') as name,
 1
  from OPENJSON(@json,'$.data') as c

select * from @tmp
```